# Why is the focus never lost from my component when I press the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jframe, focuslistener

I have a problem with the focus listener implemented by `CustomTextField` class. The focus listener is only called when another Swing component is getting the focus. But If I move the JFrame istelf by dragging it with the mouse, the `focusLost()` method is never called (in other words, it doesn´t seem that the focus is shifting from CustomTextField to JFrame).

EDIT: The solution of my question is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollFocus extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ScrollFocus();
        }
    });
}

public ScrollFocus() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Vector<String> values = new Vector<>();
    values.add("a");
    values.add("b");
    values.add("c");
    values.add("d");
    values.add("e");
    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(values);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(comboBox);
    this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    CustomTextField customTextField = new CustomTextField();
    this.add(customTextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton button = new JButton("press");
    final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu("Menu");
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("Test"));
    button.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
    this.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

class CustomTextField extends JTextField implements FocusListener {

    private CustomPopup customPopup = new CustomPopup();

    public CustomTextField() {
        this.addFocusListener(this);


        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "VK_UP");
        this.getActionMap().put("VK_UP", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setPopupSize();
                customPopup.show(CustomTextField.this, CustomTextField.this.getX(), CustomTextField.this.getY() + CustomTextField.this.getHeight());    
                customPopup.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        });
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "VK_DOWN");
        this.getActionMap().put("VK_DOWN", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setPopupSize();
                customPopup.show(CustomTextField.this, CustomTextField.this.getX(), CustomTextField.this.getY() + CustomTextField.this.getHeight());
                customPopup.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setPopupSize() {
        customPopup.setPopupSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), 110));
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    }

    class CustomPopup extends JPopupMenu {
        String[] values = new String[]{"Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value6", "Value7",
                "Value8","Value9", "Value10", "Value11", "Value12", "Value13", "Value14", "Value15", "Value16",};
        JList<String> list = new JList<>(values);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        public int index = 0;

        public CustomPopup() {
            this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
            this.add(scrollPane);
            this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                        if(customPopup.index > 0)
                            customPopup.setSelectedIndex(--customPopup.index);
                    }
                    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                        if(customPopup.index < customPopup.getListSize()-1)
                            customPopup.setSelectedIndex(++customPopup.index);
                    }
                }
            });
            this.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    index=0;
                }
            });
            pack();

        }

        public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
            list.setSelectedIndex(index);
            list.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
            requestFocus();
        }

        public int getListSize() {
            return values.length;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//customPopup.setVisible(true);
customPopup.show((JComponent)e.getSource(), 0, 20);
```

You should be using the `show(...)` method to show the popup. This must add some listeners to the popup so you will no longer need the FocusListener on the text field.

However, now this is a different problem. The text field loses focus so the Action never get invoked. That would be ok, but the JList never gains focus so it doesn't respond to the up/down keys unless you click on the list box first. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Maybe you can try to make the popup, scrollpane and list all non-focusable so that focus remains on the text field?

Comment: @camickr: Thanks camickr! `customPopup.show()` made the trick rather than `customPopup.setVisible()`. show() seems to work totally different than setVisible() since the component invoking the show() method gets the focus, but setVisible() makes the focus to be left on the JTextField. show() removes the focus from the JTextField what is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

'Focus', which is admittedly a slightly ambiguous term, generally applies to a component, not to an entire window.  We think of the "window with focus", but I think what we really mean is "the current window, the one which *contains* the focus."  I would not expect focus_lost to be called if I moved the window (aka JFrame) itself.

Another way to think of it; if I had a text field, clicked in it, and typed a letter or two, I would see those letters in that text field.  If I then moved the window slightly and typed another letter or two, I would still expect those letters to appear in that field.  It still has focus, and never lost it.

Comment: The dropdown menu of a JComboBox automatically disappears when pressing outside the component, e.g. on the JFrame. What kind of event is that? My popup menu / dropdown menu does NOT disappear when pressing on the JFrame, but on another component (as with the JComboBox).

Comment: Is this a different question?  Your original says "If I move the JFrame istelf [sic] by dragging it with the mouse, the focusLost() method is never called" -- I am not sure what you mean in this response by "pressing ... on the JFrame".

Comment: @rox Technically, when a window loses focus, the field with keybaord focus may not actually lose focus, as, technically, it still has focus within the window.  A combobox uses a special popup which is (more often then not) another window.  It has the capacity to detect changes in the window focus (which window has focus) and close it self when it loses focus...

Comment: Pressing or dragging... It does not matter for my question, I expect the focus to be lost when I interact with the JFrame. I also mentioned the JComboBox. If you press the JComboBox so its dropdown menu appears and then press the JFrame, the JComboBox´s dropdown menu disappears. I guess it is some event that the JComboBox is getting and when it is triggered, the dropdown menu is beeing hidden. When the dropdown/popup menu in my `CustomTextField` class appears, it only disappears when I press another component on the JFrame, but not if I press the JFrame itself.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I have searched the class `BasicComboPopup` for a `Window` object but it does not contain any. It is extending JPopupMenu and it seems to use a `Frame` (which is extending `Window`) so it looks like a JPopupMenu is using a Windows object at all. But I cannot see how the `Frame` is used though...

Comment: @Rox The combo boxes popup window is generate indirectly by the system (I can't remember exactly where), but in most cases, its using an undecorated window. The popup is monitoring a window lost of focus event, not a component lost focus event